# Including a module into a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  PAGE_SIZE = 33
  include MyModule

  #....
  method123

end

module MyModule
  def method123
    # .....
    a = PAGE_SIZE
  end
end
```

It throws the error: `uninitialized constant MyModule::PAGE_SIZE`.

Shouldn't `PAGE_SIZE` be visible in `MyModule` because include `MyModule` goes after definition of `PAGE_SIZE` in  MyController?

Comment: The short answer is: no.

Comment: @LoganSerman you constant `PAGE_SIZE` live in another scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better design from OOP approach is, the module resolves most dependencies by itself. So, the module should take care of page size when it needs. And page size is better a method instead of constant.

```
module MyModule
  def demo_method
    do_something_on page_size
  end

  def page_size
    33
  end
end
```

Or, if page_size should really be the job of sub class:

```
module MyModule
  def page_size
    raise "Implement it if including me!"
  end
end
```

The class who inherits this module is free to override page_size, or must override it as second block of code above.

```
class MyController
  include MyModule

  def index
    demo_method
  end

  private
  def page_size
    30
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

No, It is not possible as already explained.

But to overcome this, you can have a get function in the class and use that in the module, your code will go like this:-

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  PAGE_SIZE = 33
  include MyModule

  #....
  method123

  def get_page_size
    PAGE_SIZE    
  end
end

module MyModule
  def method123
    # .....
    a = get_page_size
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I do think you should rethink your OOP design, but here is how you can get what you want:

```
module MyModule
  def method123
    self.class.const_get("PAGE_SIZE")
  end
end
```

Using #const_get the module doesn't need to be aware of the specific name of including class, only a reference to it.